# How to install visual studio 2015 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

how can i install visual studio on Ubuntu and run it with having any crash? Tell me please because i want to move from windows operating system to Ubuntu. So help me to find a way for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Visual Studio, you won't have much luck running it on a GNU/Linux distribution like Ubuntu. Your best bet would be to try running it through Wine, but I highly doubt you will have success.

From the [Wine database page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32010) on Visual Studio 2013:

> **What works**
>
> Nothing
>
> **What does not**
>
> Install

So I'm going to assume that it won't install at all under Wine.
You could try running a virtual Windows 7 machine with [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), and then install Visual Studio there, but that'll be more resource intensive than anything.

Try another IDE, there are lots: http://alternativeto.net/software/visual-studio/